# web scraping data from glassdoor using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping, css-selectors, try-catch

please I need some help to run this code (https://github.com/PlayingNumbers/ds_salary_proj/blob/master/glassdoor_scraper.py)
In order to scrape job offer data from Glassdoor
Here's the code snippet:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd

 options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    
#Uncomment the line below if you'd like to scrape without a new Chrome window every time.
#options.add_argument('headless')
    
#Change the path to where chromedriver is in your home folder.
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
driver.set_window_size(1120, 1000)
    
url = "https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?suggestCount=0&suggestChosen=false&clickSource=searchBtn&typedKeyword="+'data scientist'+"&sc.keyword="+'data scientist'+"&locT=&locId=&jobType="
#url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/Job/jobs.htm?sc.keyword="' + keyword + '"&locT=C&locId=1147401&locKeyword=San%20Francisco,%20CA&jobType=all&fromAge=-1&minSalary=0&includeNoSalaryJobs=true&radius=100&cityId=-1&minRating=0.0&industryId=-1&sgocId=-1&seniorityType=all&companyId=-1&employerSizes=0&applicationType=0&remoteWorkType=0'
driver.get(url)

#Let the page load. Change this number based on your internet speed.
        #Or, wait until the webpage is loaded, instead of hardcoding it.
time.sleep(5)

        #Test for the "Sign Up" prompt and get rid of it.
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
time.sleep(.1)
try:
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector('[alt="Close"]').click() #clicking to the X.
    print(' x out worked')
except NoSuchElementException:
    print(' x out failed')
    pass

        
#Going through each job in this page
job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("jl")
```

I'm getting an empty list

```
job_buttons
[]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with wrong `except` argument.
With `driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()` you are trying to click non-existing element. There is no element matching "selected" class name on that page. This causes `NoSuchElementException` exception as you can see yourself while you are trying to catch `ElementClickInterceptedException` exception.
To fix this you should use the correct locator or at least the correct argument in `except`.
Like this:

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
```

Or even

```
try:
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("selected").click()
except:
    pass
```

I'm not sure what elements do you want to get into `job_buttons`.
The search results containing all the details per each job can be found by this:

```
job_buttons = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("li.react-job-listing")
```

Comment: I changed the `except` argument to `NoSuchElementException` and  now I'm getting an empty list

Comment: OK, that's better. What elements do you want to get into `job_buttons `? I see nothing matching `find_elements_by_class_name("jl")` on that page.